# search replace for 1 line

Tags: substitute

I've been following how to do search replace in vim, but somehow it doesnt work for my case.  For example, I have the following code:

```
x(i,1,1) = y(i,1,1) + z(i,1,1)
```

Now, I want to change the last index, i.e change "x(i,1,1) to x(i,1,2)" and similar for y and z.  I can just go change this manually but if I want to try our vim, just in case I have a larger expressions.

What I did: select the line visual mode `(Shift + V)`.  Then press `:`, then vim has this in the status bar `:'<,'>`, now I type: `s/,1)/,2)`.

That only changes the first variable. In other words, I have this:

```
x(i,1,2) = y(i,1,1) + z(i,1,1)
```

Y and Z are not changed, even if they are on the same line and are selected together with X in visual mode.

Please help

Answer (score 3):

So you want to make the substitution occur on every match of the pattern on the line and not only the first match. What you can do is read [`:h :s`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3As), where you'll find:

```
:[range]s[ubstitute]/{pattern}/{string}/[flags] [count]
    [...]
    See |:s_flags| for [flags].
```

So you can go to [`:h :s_flags`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3As_flags) where you'll find:

```
[g] Replace all occurrences in the line.  Without this argument,
    replacement occurs only for the first occurrence in each line.
```

So you'll add `/g` to your command like this: `:s/,1)/,2)/g` and you'll have the behavior you want.

Note that the tag `c` is often useful when you use `g`:

```
[c] Confirm each substitution.
```

Also when you use `:s` by default it operates on the current line so you don't need to visually select the line.

One last note: the UI component where you type `:'<,'>s...` is not the status line, it's the command line. The status line is the line at the bottom of a window is you set `laststatus` (see [`:h status-line`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#status-line) and [`:h Command-line`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#Command-line) to get the difference)